# Как переводить "recent answers/questions"?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Как вы считаете, как следует переводить "recent answers/questions"? Варианты из [чата](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20345364#20345364):

- последние вопросы/ответы
- недавние вопросы/ответы
- свежие вопросы/ответы

Comment: ближе всего по смыслу: «недавние». помимо этого замечал неоднократно у многих людей неприятие слова «последний» — вместо него стараются употреблять «крайний». я такой подмены не приемлю, конечно (звучит отвратительно: «крайний раз» и т.п.), но сбрасывать со счетов довольно распространённую антипатию тоже, наверно, не стоит.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: согласен, лучше бы недавние. Крайние — совсем плохо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Выбранный ответ*

«последние вопросы/ответы»

---

*Остальные ответы*.

- «свежие вопросы/ответы».
- «недавние вопросы/ответы».

Comment: Для "удалённых ответов" имеет смысл переводить как "недавние". Для подробностей [см.чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34369111#34369111).